# How to make a label display in a single line in jsf

Tags: jsf

Can any one help me to display a label in a single line?

In my UI there is a field called check funding period

but it is getting displayed in 3 lines like:

```
check                              
funding                               
period
```

what can i do so that it will display like

```
check funding period          (in single line)
```

in jsf?

Comment: Whether your code is like this <h:outputLabel for="fund" value="check funding period"/>or give your code for displaying label

Comment: Whether the label is displayed inside a table?

Comment: Can we see your JSF code for this output? It depends on what tags your using and what your wrapping them in.

Answer (score 3):

Not really a JSF question, just a CSS question.

Ensure that the label gets the CSS style `white-space:nowrap;` either via the `style` or `styleClass` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like you have your output in a column of a table and have not made sure the column is wide enough.  Use the columnClasses attribute of the dataTable to specify a css column style and make sure it is wide enough for your output.  ie:

```
<rich:dataTable id="curfDataTable"
columnClasses="column40percent,column20percent,column40percent"
rowClasses="rowFirst,rowSecond" value="#{accessCurfMBean.unowned}"
var="curf" styleClass="tableInfo">
```

Much the same for when using the panelGrid layout.

```
<h:panelGrid id="panel" columns="2" border="1" columnClasses="column40percent,column60percent">
```

and in your css:

```
.column20percent {
    width: 20%;
}

.column40percent {
    width: 40%;
}

.column60percent {
    width: 60%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is I wrap them in a h:panelGrid tag like this:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="3">
    <h:outputText value="check" />
    <h:outputText value="funding" />
    <h:outputText value="period" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

If the html output from this is too messy for you, then I would consider doing like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{Messages.check Messages.funding Messages.period}" />
```

Or simply:

```
<h:outputText value="Check funding period" />
```

As I said in the comment tho it really depends on what tags your using and what your wrapping them in. This may just be a simple CSS problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible easy solution for this problem is the **<nobr>** tag.

> Put ***<nobr>*** before your label area, and ***</nobr>*** at the end of it..
>
> ```
>   <nobr>
>     <h:outputText value="check" />
>     <h:outputText value="funding" />
>     <h:outputText value="period" />
>   </nobr>
> ```

Your problem solved!! :-)

Comment: Like as many other HTML tags which represent style rather than markup (`<center>`, `<font>`, etc), the `<nobr>` tag is **deprecated**. You shouldn't use it. The CSS `white-space: nowrap` should be used instead.